# Git post-receive not triggered

Tags: git

**Question**

Why is my Hook not executed?

**Environment & Setup**

I am working with Debian 7 and Git 1.7.10.4 - current version in official Debian repository.
There was no specific "git" Unix user created by the installation, the git repositories are however handled under an additional standard unix user not called git. It's a "bare" Git Repository.

**Hook**

Based on tutorials I created folloing Hook (I replaced the foldername), although there was no post-receive.sample file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# post-receive

REPO=/var/webs/placeholder_name.de
DATE_STAMP=$(date +%Y.%m.%d_%H:%M)
LOG=/var/log/git_hook/placeholder_name.log

echo "PUSH detected @ $DATE_STAMP ▒$1 $2 $3" >>$LOG
# 1. Read STDIN (Format: "from_commit to_commit branch_name")
from, to, branch = ARGF.read.split " "

# 2. Only deploy if master branch was pushed
if (branch =~ /master$/) == nil; then
  "Received branch #{branch}, not deploying." >> $LOG
  exit
end

# 3. Copy files to deploy directory
echo "Push at $DATE_STAMP $1 $2 $3" >> $LOG
cd $REPO && git reset --hard HEAD && git clean -f -d && git pull >> $LOG

# 4.TODO: Deployment Tasks
cd WebContent && php composer.phar update
```

**Problem**

The shell script itself is working, I am aware of the "working tree"-alternative, but this is not the issue here.
As I mentioned the script is working - if executed by ssh.
Pushing from a client however seems not to execute the Script - there is no input to the logfile.

**Git configuration**

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = true
```

**Permissions**

I expect that the push is made under the given Unix-user, in which the script is executionable, so this shouldn't be an issue as far as I am familiar with this topic.

Comment: The hook file name should be _post-receive_ and be put under .git/hooks folder.

Comment: Are you sure that the script is working? Shouldn't the first line be ```#!/usr/bin/env ruby```

Btw. don't use pull  in a script, it does a merge that might require a human to solve. Instead use git fetch and git checkout.

With never versions of git you could simplify this by just push to the repo you wan't to deploy to. You should check it out, your git version is ancient.

Comment: The missing `#` is a copy & past mistake, the one on the server contains it, sorry. I will adjust my script to avoid the pull. Nevertheless my script isn't even called. The server is running git 1.7.10.4 - the current version in the stable Debian repo, would you recommend to update the git version? It is a bare repo, so the script is in the `hook` folder.